# Show that $S^{\otimes T}=\underset{I \,is\, a\, countable\, subset\, of\, T}{\cup}\,\,\,\pi_1^{-1}(S^{\otimes I})$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, tensor-products, borel-measures

Let $S$ be a measurable space and $T$ an uncountable index set. For a subset $I\in T$, we write $\pi_1:S^T\to S^I$ for the natural projection. Show that $S^{\otimes T}=\underset{I \,is\, a\, countable\, subset\, of\, T}{\cup}\,\,\,\pi_1^{-1}(S^{\otimes I})$.

Consequently, if $S$ is a topological space with a nontrivial topology, then $B(S^T)\supset B(S)^{\otimes T} $, where $B$ refers to the Borel algebra.

Intuitively, I see why $S^{\otimes T}$ should be the limit of the $S^{\otimes I}$ taken over all the countable subsets of $T$, but I'm not sure how to prove this. I took an element of the LHS. It should belong to the RHS, which is a union, so we need to show that it belongs to one of the elements of the union, but which one? I think I can prove that $RHS\subseteq LHS$. This is because $S^{\otimes I}$ can naturally be identified with a subset of $S^{\otimes T}$ (just let the indices not in $ I$ map to $0$).

Comment: You can prove RHS $\subseteq$ LHS, so let us focus on the other inclusion. Can you show that the set on the right hand side is a $\sigma$-algebra? How is $S^{\otimes T}$ defined exactly? Presumably, it is defined as "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that some property (P) is satisfied". Can you show that the set on the right hand side also has property (P)? Because in that case you get the desired inclusion from minimality. Hope this hint helps.